# How can I hibernate my system without `sudo` access?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and am hibernating my system by `systemctl hibernate` from my terminal(GNOME). Strange thing is, while calling `poweroff`, it is going straight into shutting down my whole system with no passwords asking. But `systemctl hibernate` is going for my passwords, asking `Authentication is required to start 'hibernate.target'`.

Any work around I can have my system `hibernate` without `sudo` priviledge?